# How do I add multiple Images to my ProductManufacturers

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

So im using the CMS Shopware 6 and I want to be able to add multiple Media-Entities (e.g. Images and Videos) to my ProductManufacturers just like it is possible to add multiple images/media to products.

I have found this tutorial on the developer.shopware page: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field/add-custom-field

Also I have looked into the ProductManufacturerDefinition Class and noticed that it just needs another OneToManyAssociationField.
[Click Here to open IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGBlY.png)
Does anybody know if theres a way to overwrite this class or some other way to get this to work?

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't help just with adding a new association. You can add *[custom fields](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/custom-fields)* to add media, but one custom field can add one image only. So, one way is to create custom fields for multiple media if it's limited and you know how many images/media needs to add.

OR

You have to add multiple media upload component in the Product Manufacturers module by making a [custom plugin](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-base-guide#create-the-plugin).

Comment: ok the 2nd one sounds promising. but how would i add multiple media upload components to the Product manufacturers module. I already have a custom Plugin running on my shop.

Comment: @jakob.matijas You can extend the product manufacturer module's component and add multiple media upload component by creating a [custom definition](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities) in your custom plugin.

Comment: ah ive tried this before, but i dont think that this is for my use case. Because i want to add multiple images via the adminpanel not via code or am I wrong?